# Did the Curiosity Rover take its own hands-free selfie?

Tags: photography, nasa, mars

Time Magazine had [an article](http://time.com/2913065/mars-curiosity-rover-selfie/) with a photographic portrait of the Curiosity Rover on Mars, attributed to NSA/JPL.

Here's another version:

[image]

This photos seems like it would be impossible to take.

I would understand if it had used a monopod or any other extension from coming from its body, but how was it able to even take a photo including its optic lens?

I would even accept it if it used remote controlled drones (it's [possible](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HsxYbnT8tKk))
but from how they put it, they "combined all the photos taken by the curiosity".

Comment: my apologies, I could not find/ add proper tags to this question. There were no other topics relating to space exploration.

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is no longer about *if*, and has become about *why*.

Comment: You seem satisfied with (a) that it was done - which was the question, and (b) how it was done - which was the mystery. We have no way of definitively answering (c) *why* it was done. Isn't "that it is a cool, publicity stunt" sufficient?

Comment: yes sir. I guess that works. I'll edit out the why to keep the question acceptable

Comment: But what is the question now? You've provided an answer link in the question. What's left for us to do?

Comment: ..should I have not answered my question? I answered it mainly because I was embarrassed that I couldn't do better research on my own...

I won't mark it as accepted though. Maybe people can add more to the question.

Comment: I've fixed it now. Answering you own question is fine, but you answered it IN THE QUESTION. The Huffington post link is now only in the answer.

Answer (score 11):

[Huffington Post](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2014/06/30/how-curiosity-rover-took-selfie_n_5543343.html) shared some explanations about how the photo was captured. The Rover had used ANOTHER arm to capture the selfies. NASA then collated the selfies to produce the image.

[Here](http://www.themarysue.com/curiosity-self-portrait/) is the actual selfie taken with the camera from Curiosity's other arm.